# Dynamic variable names in a for loop

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am working with a form that needs to be populated with values taken from cookies. The id's of the form elements correspond to cookie names:

```
<label>ABC: </label>
<input type="text" id="ABC" />
<br />

<label>DEF: </label>
<input type="text" id="DEF" />
<br />

<label>GHI: </label>
<input type="text" id="GHI" />
<br />

<label>JKL: </label>
<input type="text" id="JKL" />
<br />
```

Originally I just wrote a separate snippet for getting cookie value for each form:

```
  var ABCdata = getCookie("ABC");
  var ABCfield = document.getElementById('ABC');
  ABCfield.value = ABCdata; 

  var DEFdata = getCookie("DEF");
  var DEFfield = document.getElementById('DEF');
  DEFfield.value = DEFdata;

  var GHIdata = getCookie("GHI");
  var GHIfield = document.getElementById('GHI');
  GHIfield.value = GHIdata;

  var JKLdata = getCookie("JKL");
  var JKLfield = document.getElementById('JKL');
  JKLfield.value = JKLdata;
```

But then I thought of rewriting this as array and loop:

```
var cookienames = new Array();

cookienames[0] = "ABC";
cookienames[1] = "DEF";
cookienames[2] = "GHI";
cookienames[3] = "JKL";

for (var i=0; i<cookienames.length; i++) {
var cookienames[i]+"data" = getCookie(cookienames[i]);
var cookienames[i]+"field" = document.getElementById(cookienames[i]);
cookienames[i]+"field".value = cookienames[i]+"data";
}
```

Somehow, the array solution doesn't work: the form fields do not get populated with data. I suspect, the dynamic variable names are to blame.

What is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: You mean, why do I name them "ABCdata" and "ABCfield"?

Comment: You just don't need variables for that case as you can do everything in a single operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use different variables inside the loop. Try simply

```
var cookienames = ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL"],
    field,
    data, 
    cn;

for (var i = 0, cl = cookienames.length; i < cl; i++) {
   cn = cookienames[i];                  // get cookie name
   data = getCookie(cn);                 // read cookie value
   field = document.getElementById(cn);  // retrieve field
   field.value = data;                   // set field value
}
```

(As a sidenote, it's a good practice to previously cache the length of the array)

Comment: Thank you, @Fabrizio, this is very valuable. Coule you please explain to me a little more about the structure of the array declaration that you used, I find it very interesting, but not familiar...

Comment: When you create an array you can declare an empty structure to fill later (as you did) but you may also list soon all the values between square brackets, and values must be comma-separated (except the last one): [see MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Thanks, @Fabrizio, I got that part, but what I'm interested in is things you added after the comma: `field, data, cn;` could you please explain that structure, and maybe point me to where I could read about that?

Comment: `var a, b, c;` is just a shortcut for `var a; var b; var c;`

Answer (score 4):

Did you try this :

```
document.getElementById(cookienames[i]).value = getCookie(cookienames[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not "create" variables dynamically using the `var` keyword this way.

But since every global variable is a property of `window`, you can do it like this:

```
window[cookienames[i]+"data"] = getCookie(cookienames[i]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @CBroe, I learned something very valuable!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why you want to use intermediate variable, this should work

```
var cookienames = new Array();

cookienames[0] = "ABC";
cookienames[1] = "DEF";
cookienames[2] = "GHI";
cookienames[3] = "JKL";

for (var i=0; i<cookienames.length; i++) {
  var data = getCookie(cookienames[i]);
  document.getElementById(cookienames[i]).value = data;
}
```